# IPv6 Compatibility for GoDaddy VPS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, ipv6

I have a GoDaddy VPS running Windows Server 2008, I use it to host my main website as well as the REST APIs that I use in my mobile application.

When I tried to submit to iTunes, my app got rejected due to IPv6 incompatibility. I have already added the AAAA record to my DNS, I have the domain binding in IIS on port 80 set to "All Unassigned" and the IPv6 address shows in the IIS dropdown when binding so supposedly my server has an IPv6 address.

However, the IPv6-test.com recognizes my AAAA record but the web server remains unreachable (As per the screenshot below).

Is there any specific settings on Windows Firewall or IIS that I should do? Should I add specific domain bindings for the IPv6 address?

Thank you,[IPv6 Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgv3R.jpg)

Comment: That IPv6 address is a 6to4 address. This isn't going to work. Remove that DNS record and test your application again, according to [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16).

Comment: I removed it and the test stopped at the first step. It looks for an AAAA record first.

Comment: You have no need to run that test. You need to fix your application.

Comment: The application uses REST APIs that I call using domain name not specific IP addresses. The issue is that the APIs are not reacheable using IPv6

Comment: Again, that is not why Apple rejected your app. Follow Apple's instructions.